# Using an image loaded in one class in another

Tags: java, image, class, instance

How would I be able to do this? I plan on having a class with every single image in my game, and then using that to carry out what i need done in each class. I don't need code, a simple answer is fine (Code would be appreciated though).

Comment: Add a method to the 1st class that has access to the frame.  Call that method from the 'other class'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson , so i would for example make a method called " getpics() " in my main class. Then in my image class make a method called " loadpics() " ? How would i call it from my main class? I am very sorry, but i'm new to programming.

Comment: I would tend to have the 'to' class declare an `addImage(Image)` method.  The 'from' class then calls `to.addImage(Image)`.